# Creating nested routes for pages that use acts_as_tree

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Page model that goes 1 generation deep.  How can I do my routes so that

/about

/about/leadership

/about/vision-and-mission

/contact

/join

/join/benefits

work?

The slugs come from the friendly_id plugin, and are all unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your routes:

```
  map.with_options :controller => 'pages' do |pages|
    pages.show_page                ':id',              :action  => 'show'
    pages.show_page_with_parent    ':id/:parent_id',   :action  => 'show'
  end
```

If you wand to generate a link to it:

```
show_page_with_parent_path(:id => page.name, :parent_id => page.parent.name)
```

This, of course, assuming that the slug key is the name.

You may, of course, further customise this solution, with a helper function:

EG:

```
def custom_show_page_path(page)
  if page.parent.nil?
    show_page_path(:id => page.name)
  else
    show_page_with_parent_path(:id => page.name, :parent_id => page.parent.name)
  end
end
```